# How to pass data from VB.net to C++ and vice versa?

Tags: c++, vb.net, unmanaged

I am doing an application that has a UI made by VB.net.
The VB.net collects all user input data, and I need to pass it to unmanaged C++ to process the data.
My current approach is to save the data from VB.net to binary files, and use C++ to read those binary files. But I feel like there might be a better alternative. Do you have any experience with that sort of situation and what is your suggestion?

Regards
T.

Comment: Look into Platform Invoke (pinvoke). It is how .NET code invokes Windows API functions so there is plenty of information and examples around. You use the same principles to invoke functions exported from any C/C++ libraries. This, of course, assumes that you're not dealing with a COM component.

Comment: there are certain classic ways - pipes, sockets, etc. A better alternative would be subjective to your use case.